# How to execute a module from a package imported with importlib

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have a module in a package called `testpackageB`

module is called `testb.py` with contents:

```py
__all__ = ['testb']


def testb():
    print("Hello World from Test B in testpackageB")
```

The `__init__.py` file the package directory contains:

```py
from testpackageB import testb
```

The code to import this module dynamically is as follows:

```py
import importlib


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tt = importlib.import_module(".testb", "testpackageB")

    print(type(tt))  # Shows: <class 'module'>

    # All of the following do not work:
    #  tt["testb"]()
    #  tt()
    #  tt.testb()
```

What I don't understand and can't find is a simple answer on the question:

**How do I execute testpackageB.testb in this main function?**

---

After getting comments I learned that `tt.testb()` is working.

But that is not the one you want. Because 'testb' is dynamic, so you have that name in a variable.

See this code: (slightly changed)

```py
    module = "testb"
    package = "testpackageB"
    tt = importlib.import_module(f".{module}", package)

    tt["module"]().  # Gives error: TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```

So, I rephrase the question:

**How do I execute testpackageB.testb in this main function,**

**with `testpackageB` and `testb` in variables?**

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. `tt.testb()` is working for me.

Comment: if you get error message then show it in question. It seems code works on other computers. And we can't read in your mind.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But `tt.testb()` is the one you don't want because `testb` is in a variable. See my updated question. Hope you can help me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

### How to execute a dynamically imported package-module-function

##### Folder structure:

```bash
- testpackageB
   - testb.py
       def testb(): ....

- main.py
```

##### testpackageB/testb.py

```py
__all__ = ['testb']

def testb():
    print("Hello World from testb in testpackageB")
```

##### testpackageB/**init**.py

```py
from testpackageB import testb
```

##### main.py

```py
import importlib

if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    package = "testpackageB"
    module = "testb"
    function = "testb"
    tt = importlib.import_module(f".{module}", package)

    func = getattr(tt, function)
    if func:
        func()
```